# Django's testserver returns JSON ok, but nginx returns junk

Tags: django, nginx, fastcgi

i have nginx as a proxy to django default fcgi server.

The problem is django default server(manage runserver) works ok, but nginx + fcgi connection doesnt on returning JSON.Other types are ok - js,css,img ok
headers returned and json are.

default-

---

headers:

```
Content-Type:application/json
Date:Thu, 03 Oct 2013 01:02:05 GMT
Server:WSGIServer/0.1 Python/2.7.3
```

json:{"amount": 3000.0, "limit": 0.0,etc....}

nginx:

---

headers:

```
Connection:keep-alive
Content-Encoding:gzip
Content-Type:text/html; charset=utf-8
Date:Thu, 03 Oct 2013 01:04:03 GMT
Server:nginx/1.1.19
Transfer-Encoding:chunked
```

json - Ð‘Ð°Ð»Ð°Ð½Ñ

What or where can be the problem? Nginx config or may be

Answer (score 0):

You seems to have nginx configured to gzip compression and your client library doesn't seem to understand gzip. Switch to use a client networking library that understands HTTP and HTTP  compression.